# How to add security group in SecurityGroupIngress from other VPC in AWS cloud formation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

We have got multiple AWS accounts. While creating CFTemplate for Security group creation, I should add SG from other VPC as inbound rule. When I try the same code with "CidrIp", my stack is created without error but when I give `SourceSecurityGroupId` & `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`. I'm getting an error as the given VPC does not exist This is the code I used.

```
"Resources" : {
    "PrivateWindowsSg" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
         "GroupDescription" : "Ingress from AD & DC in CS",
         "VpcId" : {
           "Ref" : "VPCID"
         }
      }
    },
    "PrivateWindowsSgIngress" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      "Properties" :{
          "Description" : "Ingress from AD & DC in CS",
          "GroupId" : {
            "Ref" : "PrivateWindowsSg"
          },
          "IpProtocol" : "UDP",
          "FromPort" : "49152",
          "ToPort" : "65535",
          "SourceSecurityGroupId" : "SG from Other VPC",
          "SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId" :"AWSAccountID"
          }
        }
      }
```

The error I'm getting every time is

> The security group 'sg-055f0xxxx' does not exist in the default VPC 'none' (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; Request ID: 056cc269-421d-4985-a15a-b672f20041c8)

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the source security group you are trying to add comply with the following:

> Another security group. This allows instances associated with the specified security group to access instances associated with this security group. This does not add rules from the source security group to this security group. You can specify one of the following security groups:
>
> - The current security group
> - A different security group for the same VPC
> - A different security group for a peer VPC in a VPC peering connection

If not, you will not be able to add it.  See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for more information.  You can also test this by trying to do it manually via the Admin console.  If it works there, then you should be able to do it w/ CloudFormation, if not, well then you know where your problem is.

Comment: Yeah! Your are correct. I didn't check the VPC peering before. It is working fine now.

Comment: @Bhargavi You probably shouldn't create another answer stating the same.  I recommend you accept my answer and if you need to, add your answer as a comment to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my code to be working. The problem is not from the code but from testing template from wrong VPC that doesn't have peering connection to destination VPC.